# Why getting an exception when calling Invoke?

Tags: c#

I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when trying to call the `Invoke()` function on my form. I use the delegate pattern to avoid illegal cross thread calls, since the `addAgentToList()` function is called by another thread (not the one that handles the GUI).

Why do I get the following exception?

[image]

```
    public void addAgentToList(Agent agent) {
        if(lstAgents.InvokeRequired) {
            OnAddAgentToList callback = new OnAddAgentToList(addAgentToList);
            this.Invoke(callback, new object[] { agent });
        } else {
            lstAgents.BeginUpdate();
            try {
                if(!isAgentOnList(agent)) {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(agent.Name+" @ "+agent.Address.ToString());
                    item.Tag = agent;
                    item.ImageIndex = 0;
                    lstAgents.Items.Add(item);
                }
            } finally {
                lstAgents.EndUpdate();
            }
            // select agent
            if(lstAgents.SelectedIndices.Count==0) {
                if(lstAgents.Items.Count>0) {
                    lstAgents.Items[0].Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private bool isAgentOnList(Agent agent) {
        foreach(ListViewItem item in lstAgents.Items) {
            Agent listAgent = (Agent)item.Tag;
            if(agent==listAgent) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the exception as textual representation:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Value of '1' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'Minimum' and 'Maximum'.
```

Comment: I would say there is an issue somewhere in the isAgentOnList method, can you show the code for that method?

Comment: Make sure you put the *text* of the exception and inner exception in the body of your question (and *not* just in an image). The inner exception seems to be telling you that something is not a valid value. Did you look at that?

Comment: Add the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` to the Visual Studio exceptions break list.  Use `Ctrl+Alt+E` keyboard shortcut or the `Debug` menu.  Then rerun your test and it should break at the point where the exception occurs.  It looks like it trying to set a Form property with an out of range value.

Comment: Using Invoke() is a pretty bad practice in general, it is only truly necessary when you need its return value.  Use BeginInvoke() instead, now the exception becomes debuggable.

Comment: I haven't tried your code. Can you report back your results after checking the following:
1) check value of "agent" before Invoke
2) check number of times Invoke line is run

Comment: Thanks for the numerous response. I found the solution to my issue. I was trying to set a trackbar's value out of range. Now it works.

Comment: Btw. I added a textual representation of the exceptions and added the `isAgentOnList` function definition, but the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` was thrown on another position, which was called when building the panel after the agent was added to the list.

Comment: I tried `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`. But when doing so, I get an even less accurate exception from the debugger. It stops on `Application.Run` method call with a `TargetInvocationException` without any hint where to look for the problem.